# (Table Calendar Flutter) How to get data from external link JSON to replace _events

Tags: json, flutter, calendar

How to get data from external link JSON to replace _events . So the events data get from JSON not hardcode into the file. Please help Thanks you

```
class MuditaCalendar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MuditaCalendarState createState() => _MuditaCalendarState();
}

class _MuditaCalendarState extends State<MuditaCalendar> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  DateTime _selectedDay;

  Map<DateTime, List> _events;
  Map<DateTime, List> _visibleEvents;
  List _selectedEvents;
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedDay = DateTime.now();
    _events = {
      DateTime.parse("2019-03-31") : ['Event A6', 'Event B6'],
      DateTime.parse("2019-03-15") : ['Event A7', 'Event B6'],
      DateTime.parse("2019-03-02") : ['Event A6', 'Event B6'],
      DateTime.parse("2019-03-13") : ['Event A6', 'Event B6'],
    };
    _selectedEvents = _events[_selectedDay] ?? [];
    _visibleEvents = _events;

    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    );

    _controller.forward();
  }
}
```

Comment: I solved the json thing here the code

  Future getData() async {
      _events = {};
      final response = await http.get("http://muditacenter.com/aplikasi/get_data.php");
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        _events[DateTime.parse(jsonData[i]['tanggal'])] = jsonData[i]['judul'];
       }
  }

Answer (score 1):

I solved the json thing here the code

```
  Future getData() async {
      _events = {};
      final response = await http.get("http://muditacenter.com/aplikasi/get_data.php");
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        _events[DateTime.parse(jsonData[i]['tanggal'])] = jsonData[i]['judul'];
       }
  }
```

JSON EXAMPLE :

```
[{"tanggal":"2019-04-07","judul":["Cheng Beng"]},{"tanggal":"2019-04-21","judul":["Asthasila222 (八關齋戒).\r\n","Kegitan lainnya","Kegitan lainnya 2"]}]
```